# Why is this function firing multiple times?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm filling this list:

```
<ul id="FolderList"></ul>
```

with a list of folders using jquery that produces the following HTML:

```
<ul id="FolderList">
    <li id="FolderList0" onclick="return myFunc(0)">Item 1</li>
    <li id="FolderList1" onclick="return myFunc(1)">Item 2</li>
    <li id="FolderList2" onclick="return myFunc(2)">Item 3
        <ul>
            <li id="FolderList2a" onclick="return myFunc(2a)">Sub Item 1</li>
            <li id="FolderList2b" onclick="return myFunc(2b)">Sub Item 2
                <ul>
                    <li id="FolderList2bi" onclick="return myFunc(2bi)">Subsub Item 1</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>          
    </li>
</ul>
```

...

```
function myFunc(id) {
//do something
```

return false;
    };

For some reason if i click on a level 1 li item, the function myFunc() executes as expected. If i click on a "level 2" item (ie: FolderList2a), myFunc is being called twice.  If i click on a 3rd level (ie: FolderList2bi) it gets called 3 times - and so on.
Anyone know what's going on here?!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please do not use onclick attribute to bind events. Use JavaScript.

Comment: Btw, you can't nest LI inside LI directly. LI have to be children of UL (or OL).

Comment: Thanks Sime, I took the lazy way out and didn't nest in the UL's, but now i have, thinking that it would fix the "bubbling" issue that everyone pointed out below. Didn't fix the problem, but my HTML is now more up to standards :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The click events are [bubbling](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow-bubbling) up the Dom
<s>If you want to prevent bubbling let `myFunc` return false</s>

To stop the bubbling you'll need to access the event object, `event.stopPropagation` or `event.cancelBubble` depending on browser.

http://jsfiddle.net/Jetyc/3/

Comment: I checked out everyone's post about "bubbling" and this is indeed consistent with what i'm experiencing. Adding "return false" to the end of the function didn't fix it :(

Comment: Well with the code you posted it doesn't even bubble. http://jsfiddle.net/Jetyc/, is that the actual code

Comment: no, the actual code is much longer since it has two jquery functions: the first one gets a JSON results and uses that to build the list above. The second one I've struggled with trying to wire it up to a  click event. I wasn't sure if it wasn't working because the elements were being built by the first jquery function, so i ended up adding an onclick event to the elements direclty, which started this whole bubbling//cascading event problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass a string as an argument, so quote it:

```
                                             .--.-----------------
                                             v  v
<li id="FolderList2a" onclick="return myFunc('2a')">Sub Item 1</li>
```

And also place `return false` in the end of your function:

```
function myFunc(id) {
    //do something

    return false;
};
```

Comment: I've updated the onclick to match yours (added return...) and at the end of my function, i added "return false".  It's still calling it as many times as the listitem is nested.

Comment: @Losbear Try to update your code with the valid nested list constructions as noted by [Šime Vidas in the comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334791/why-is-this-function-firing-multiple-times/11334804#comment14923914_11334791).

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.bind()` instead to avoid bubbling up the DOM.

```
$("#FolderList li").bind("click", function() {
//do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The event fires multiple times because it bubbles.
You can read more about the event bubbling, for example, here:
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you are encountering is called Event Bubbling.

When you click on a nested set of elements, the click is first sent to the deepest element in the hierarchy and then it goes up in the hierarchy.

see an example on [MDN Event propagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_DOM_Reference/Examples#Example_5%3a_Event_Propagation)

Comment: Link is dead (9 years later).