# Getting response back from server but .html not sowing anything in wordpress ajax

Tags: ajax, wordpress

On click I'm sending the id as data and then using query showing the name of user from WordPress database. I'm getting the response back from server but It is not adding when try to use .html(response).May be this is something to do with permission ?Like only admin can use the response?
If that's the case what I can do.

This is the ajax function:

```
    function get_user_id() {
    let get_current_user_id =jQuery(this).attr('id');
    cur_user = '<?php echo get_current_user_id() ;?>';
    var postdata_name = {action: "incoming_user_name_ajax_call",
    param_user_to_chat: get_current_user_id,};

    jQuery.post(ajaxurl, postdata_name, function (response) {
    jQuery("#name-incoming-user").html(response);});

}
```

This is the function in functions.php

```
  add_action("wp_ajax_incoming_user_name_ajax_call", "incoming_user_name_ajax_call_fn");
  add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_incoming_user_name_ajax_call", "incoming_user_name_ajax_call_fn");


   function incoming_user_name_ajax_call_fn() {
   global $wpdb;
   $param_user_to_chat=isset($_REQUEST['param_user_to_chat'])?trim($_REQUEST['param_user_to_chat']):"";

   if (!empty($param_user_to_chat)) {

   $posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT distinct(display_name) FROM wp_users where  
   ID=$param_user_to_chat");
   echo $posts[0]->display_name;

  }
  wp_die();}
```

Posting the HTML as well for everyone who want to know what jQuery(this).attr('id'); is doing. It is getting id "4" or "2" depending on click.

```
<div id="target">
  <div class="user-list-hide" id="user-hide" style="display: block;">
   <div id="4"><span>Jason Bradley</span>/div>
   <div id="2"><span>John Saddington</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, what is `jQuery(this).attr('id');` here ? Also , are you able to see response ? do `alert(response)` see if that showing correct data .

Comment: @Swati   jQuery(this).attr('id') it is id of user. alert(response) is returning user as per click on  jQuery(this).attr('id')  : (Jason Bradley)

Comment: So, response is successfully return ?

Comment: @swati Alert is  firing two times. Not sure why .Though I have only One alert in code.
First time it is returning correct result. "Jason Bradley" .Then it is getting null values.

Comment: @Swati On first alert it is showing child div id (4) that is ok but on next alert it is getting parent div that is user-hide.Is there anything wrong with jQuery(this).attr('id');?

Comment: I am still wondering.. how are you able to get correct id here `jQuery(this).attr('id')` .. because there is no reference for `this`. Also , maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334791/why-is-this-function-firing-multiple-times) might be helpful.

Comment: @swati beause I've added jQuery("#target").on("click", "div", get_user_id);  I'll check the link you share. Thanks

Comment: change `jQuery("#target").on("click", "div", get_user_id);` to `jQuery("#user-hide").on("click", "div", get_user_id);` see if that works .

Comment: @swati Yes that was the issue. thanks. I've changed it to jQuery("#target #user-hide").on("click", "div", get_user_id); and it works. Please post it as answer I will accept. Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was issue in your jquery code i.e : the way you were calling your `get_user_id()` function here you have use wrong selector to get your inner divs . So, to make it work change :

```
jQuery("#target").on("click", "div", get_user_id);
```

to

```
jQuery("#user-hide").on("click", "div", get_user_id);
```

Comment: Yes Got it .Thanks.